# Inserting 13k PDF Attachments each 192kb in Attachments object

Tags: data-loader, attachment, heapsizelimit

I want to insert 13k PDF attachments in Salesforce. Each of the PDF is 192 kb.  I have created a csv file with the name of the pdf and it's relative path on the local drive.

[image]

I tested inserting 15 attachments successfully.  However, if I upload a csv with all 13 k records, I am afraid I may run into a **Maximum Size of Request Reached** error

Apart from splitting the 13k into small files, which is a mammoth task, **is there a better way to upload the 13 k attachments. ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is all about the size of the batch or request that you do. You're not pushing all 13k all at once you're pushing chunks based on the data loader's batch size setting.

If 15 went through that's good, you could set you batch to that but maybe try 100 or 200? 13k will take a while 15 records at a time. But it'll work for you.

Comment: [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_bulkapi.htm) suggests that the limit per batch is 10MB (150MB for Bulk API 2.0). That'd put the limit at somewhere around 50 (v1) or 750 (v2).